# Hide only download, print option in the pdf viewer using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, pdf-viewer

Used `#end{ display:none; }`  not worked
[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgjll.png)

Want to hide only the red part using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
#end{ 
display:none !important;
}
```

or

```css
#end{ 
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not working. Can you suggest any pdf viewer library used in javascript to view pdf in iframe? . Bascially , I want all feature of pdf except (download and print option).